# How to prevent nested subscribe in get operation?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular2-observables

I get data from objects and images, here is the code:

```
  this.getObjects(id)
  .subscribe(param => param.results.map(r=> this.getImmagesByObjectId(r.id)
    .subscribe(data=>console.log(data, param))))
```

as you can see for this purpose I first fetch objects and the inner observable
based on objects id I fetch objects images.

I try to prevent a nested suscription, for this purpose I try to use merge all operator:

```
  this.getObjects(id).pipe(mergeMap
  (param => param.results.map(r=> this.getImmagesByObjectId(r.id))
    .subscribe(data=>console.log(data, param))))
```

But the code above doesn't work.

My question is how to fetch the objects and images from the server and prevent nested subscribe?

UPDATE:

Here is GetObjects implementation as you can see it returms observable:

```
  getObjects(Id: string): Observable<Response<MyObjects[]>> {
    return this.clientObjects.get<Response<MyObjects[]>>(environment.baseUrl + '/main/myobjects/byobjid', {
      params: {
        id: Id
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using `flatMap` (alias `mergeMap`) and `from` operator

```
this.getObjects(id)
  .flatMap(param => from(param.results)) // `from` to convert array to observable
  .flatMap(result => this.getImmagesByObjectId(result.id)
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data)))) // data contains image
```

alternatively, if we want to see `param` in `console.log` in `subscribe` method

```
this.getObjects(id)
  .flatMap(param => { 
    return from(param.results)
      .pipe(
        flatMap(result => this.getImmagesByObjectId(result.id))
        map(image => ({image, param})) // return both image and param as object
      )
  ))   
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data.image, data.param))))
```

Comment: Your solution suffers from a lack of concurrency

Comment: Thank you for the post, I added implementation of  getObjects this is service that return Obsetvable , what should I use from operator